# Pandas: How to make bar vertical in style?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Excel, in the cell it only allows to make horizontal data bar by the value given in that cell.

[image: Options]

So I thought that Pandas would be more flexible, but couldn't find parameters to do so. Is it, how, possible to do vertical bar b) instead of horizontal bar a)? Data arangement has to stay fixed, so transposing data is not an option.

Is it something with `df.style.bar()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option but one could patch the CSS after it is generated by replacing:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg,
```

With:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg,
```

And then one would have to adjust the table cells so that they are tall rather than wide.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Bar-charts